# Reference new object through void method

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on an assignment that deals with array manipulations for Java. Right now I have to delete elements inside the middle of an array. Now I know that arrays, once they're created cannot be changed in length. So I decided to make a new object, and have the former reference point to my new array.

```
public class A{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    B test = new B(val);
    test.cut(2,4);
    test.display();
  }

class B{    
  private Obj[] array;

  B(Obj val){
    construct something
  }

  public void cut(int i, int j){
     B newObject = new B(val);
        ...
     newObject.array = this.array;
     newObject = this;
  }
}
```

The issue is that when I display the test object, it will only show me the original test object contents rather than newObject contents. Since this is a void method, I can't return an object. How do I reference the new object then? The last two lines for my cut method seem to have no effect at all. I know that ArrayList would be preferable for things like this, but this being a homework assignment we are forced to use arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I know that arrays, once they're created cannot be changed in length.

This is true.

But the **reference** pointing to an array inside the `B` object instance *can* be changed (as you didn't declare it `final`):

```
public void cut(int i, int j){

   Object[] newArray = new Object[len];

    //...  copying array content ...

   this.array = newArray;
}
```

Beware of the **thread safety issues** such mutability causes. Mutable objects are usually frowned upon...

Comment: Wow that's so much smarter. I can't believe I didn't think of that. And it works!!! I've been creating entire objects willy-nilly and I kept thinking that felt reckless. Would you recommend that it's better to just change the field references as opposed to object references?

Answer (score 0):

If the rules of assignment allow the use of class [`Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28T%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29), this is what you can use instead of your own `cut` method:

```
newArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(oldArray, from, to);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the method `cut` you create a new object of `B` then assign the the `this` reference to it. This has not effect as you have found because the `this` reference (the actual object) is not changed at all, The `newObject` is visible only inside this method, once it is terminated, the object is gone.

While you are in the same class `B` you dont have to create a new Object of it just for the purpose of altering the data it holds. You could just create a new array and copy the original content to it.

For copying the content you could use the method [System#arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29). If you are not permited to use any jdk helping functionalities, then you could just loop over the original array and copy elements into the new one as you want.

Comment: Similar suggestion as ppeterka66 although I didn't use any other methods like copy. Thank you though!